# @FormParam or @FormDataParam when getting angular http POST formData?

Tags: java, angularjs, http, https, jersey

I want to pass from my angularjs client data to the server:

here is my client:

```
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('voice', voice);
        formData.append('isAddMode', isAddMode);
        $http.put('/api/Voices/updateVoice', formData).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
```

or:

```
        $http.put('/api/Voices/updateVoice', {voice: voice, isAddMode : isAddMode}).then(
```

here is my server

```
public void updateVoice(@FormDataParam("voice") VoiceBl voice, @FormParam("isAddMode") boolean isAddMode) throws Exception {
```

how should I modify the server API to get the POST request with multi params properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this and then cast the Object to correct Class:

```
@POST 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void create(final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> formParams) {
  VoiceBl voice = (VoiceBl) formParams.get("voice");
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat certain you cannot receive customized classes such as VoiceB1 as a parameter of an HTTP service in Java. You can, however, as @FrAn answered, receive a MAP (which is basically a JSON object viewed differently) and convert it into your class. There are various ways to do it. This is how I do it anyways.

Comment: is it better to use FormData? or json object from the client side?